# Fetching the values of dynamic textboxes vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If i have multiple textboxes with the same Id and name in a form, how to fetch there values separately in vb.net? can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

in javascript iv used fetched them like this

```
var b=document.getElementById('TextBox') 
var a=b.length; 
for(var i=0; i<a; i++) { 
var text=b[i]; 
alert(text) 
}
```

Comment: Are they in a repeater or repeater-like container control?

Comment: are these asp.net textbox controls or html input boxes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for vb.net

```
For Each oControl As Control In Page.Controls
            If TypeOf oControl Is TextBox Then
                Dim txtbox As TextBox = CType(oControl, TextBox)
                txtbox.Text = Date.Now.ToString
            End If
        Next
```

in your case something like this assuming your textboxes ids are like txtTestTxt0, txtTestTxt1,txtTestTxt2 and so on

```
   For x As var = 0 To Page.Controls
    If Page.FindControls("txtTestTxt" & x) IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("txtTestTxt" & x.tostring()), TextBox)
        myval = tb.Text
    End If
Next
```

Comment: my text box ids are not like txtTestTxt0, txtTestTxt1 like this.. all ids are same textTest..

Answer (score 2):

You should have a seperate ID from them. How are you generating those text boxes ?

Generate the textboxes in a loop and assign them the incrementing IDs, for ex box1,box2 ....

Comment: yes i have generated them in a loop. But i want to have same name and ID for them. in javascript iv used fetched them like this var b=document.getElementById('TextBox') 
var a=b.length; 
for(var i=0; i<a; i++) {
var text=b[i];
alert(text)
}
and it is giving me desired result
how to do this in vb???

Comment: ok.. can u please provide a sample? it will be good. im a novice in vb.net. :) thanks..